present participle or past participle which is correct
I got this sentence in someone translation. I think it should ing form used
Please correct me if I am wrong.

A country that exists for you in a remembered fragrance.

As we learned it is a grammar rule
We use the ing form to describe things or persons that are the source of effect and the past participle is for the receiver of the effect.
So, I think it should be as follows:

A country that exists for you in a remembering fragrance.

Am I right or not ?

A remembered fragrance - a fragrance remembered by you. A remembering fragrance - a fragrance that remembers something (which is meaningless because a scent can't remember things).

The first utterance is very unusual, even as "poetic" phrasing (slightly less so with as instead of in). But I guess that's because it's a translation, not reflective of normal English utterances,
But the revised version is simply ungramatical - it's not acceptable in any context.
There are contexts where a continuous participle is used adjectivally (stewing beef, say). But this isn't one of them, and past participle is far more common for adjectival contexts anyway (stewed beef).

If you want to use a present participle, you could say "fragrance you're remembering".

But then it's 100% verb, with not even a hint of adjective. You're remembering isn't the same construction as She's [very] fetching.

yeah, I was wondering that as I wrote it. BTW, an even more common example of a present continuous participle is "boiling water" -- we hardly ever talk about boiled water (which is either just hot water or steam, depending on perspective).

Well, boiling fowl is a tough old bird destined for coq au vin, with an "adjectival" continuous participle. But we don't often refer to adjectivally-modified boiling water that's intended to become potable after being boiled. As opposed to washing water that's only suitable for cleaning purposes. (And Victorian ladies "at their toilet", not today's common or garden toilet which needs to be supplied with flushing water :)

And in some contexts (like if you don't want your guts infested by parasites when camping or living off-grid, or if your local water supply company have been experiencing "problems"), you might be very particular about only drinking boiled water, not the bucket of potentially unsafe river water that's only for washing.

This is not a fully answer to my question. I just want to add a new note.
The box of replying is not typically enough to post more than 100- 150 words.
Using both participles in my example are not common. However, I want to add a few examples showing why the present participle is not used.
Example:
This is a fried fish. (not frying) the fish can't make sense of frying or brings to someone the action of frying. ( no effect)
I need a boiled egg.
in the example ( boiling water or walking stick )  the stick can't walk, the water can't boil itself
( so these ing forms are gerunds not doing the action of participles but as nouns  --- " compound nous" )
Examples: present participle

It was a tiring journey. 2. I read an interesting novel.

I am interested in the novel ---- it is interesting for me.
It can make sense on me that I get interested in
The method of explaining is also applicable to example one.

OP has asked:


A country that exists for you in a remembered fragrance.
A country that exists for you in a remembering fragrance.


The first sentence can be understood but using"remembered" as an adjective is not common.
The second sentence doesn't have a clear meaning.
In OP's extension of the question

in the example ( boiling water or walking stick ) the stick can't walk, the water can't boil itself
( so these ing forms are gerunds not doing the action of participles but as nouns --- " compound nouns" )

In all the examples participles are used as adjectives and they aren't gerunds or compound nouns..
"boiling water" means water which is boiling.
"walking stick" means stick which is used for walking.
"running shoes" - used for running.
"gardening tools" - used for gardening.
Similarly
"boiled eggs" eggs that has been boiled
"fried chicken" that has been fried.
"smoked salmon" that has been smoked.
"frozen vegetables" that has been frozen.

The Elements of English Grammar with a Chapter on Essay-writing
By Alfred Slater West  Please just read here  :  Observe that in compound nouns the form in –ing is frequently gerundive. Thus a walking-stick is a stick for walking; a fishing-rod is a rod for fishing. If these forms in ing were participles, a walking-stick would be a stick that walked and a fishing-rod a rod that fished, just as a talking- fish is a fish that talks and a laughing-hyena a hyena that laughs

And also from here : page 82  English Grammar: With Chapters on Composition, Versification, Paraphrasing By John Miller Dow Meiklejohn  >  In the words walking-stick, frying-pan, etc., walking and frying are nouns, and therefore gerunds. If they were adjectives and participles, the compounds would mean the stick that walks, the pan that fries

page 11 Modern English Syntax
By C.T. Onionsa noun or verb-noun forming part of a compound noun: cannon balls (= balls for cannon; see 5 above) walking sticks (= sticks for walking)
head wind (= a wind from the front)
sick room (= the room for the sick; see 5 above and §17.3.
Cf. sick bay, -bed, -benefit, -call, -list.)

@AhmadMohammad It depends which grammar book you are referring. Some grammar books prefer to classify these -ing forms in compound nouns as adjectives because they modify the noun by indicating what type of stick or rod it is (a stick for walking, a rod for fishing). This is an adjectival role, since it describes the function or purpose of the object, even if it still references an action.
